# How to calculate a matrix-matrix derivative

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm having trouble understanding how to differentiate a matrix-matrix multiplication, and was wondering if anyone had a good textbooks and/or examples that could help me learn the details of this technique.

The function at hand is,
$$ Y = AX + C $$

where X is a matrix of size (B,N), A is a matrix of size (N,H), C is a matrix of size (B,H), and Y is a matrix of size (B,H). Where, B, N, and H are scalar values to indicate the size of these matrices. I was using the website http://www.matrixcalculus.org/ to calculate the answer, although this doesn't help me understand the underlying principles behind it, and secondly it's not entirely clear to me as a beginner.

For example, the website states,
$$ \displaystyle{\frac{\partial Y}{\partial A} \left( A\cdot X+C \right) = X^\top \otimes \mathbb{I}}$$
and,
$$ \displaystyle{\frac{\partial Y}{\partial C} \left( A\cdot X+C \right) = \mathbb{I}\otimes \mathbb{I}} $$

Also, given that it states the identity matrix $\mathbb{I}$ however, the dimensions of it aren't clear to me if it has a size of (N,N) or (H,H)?

So, for $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}$ would be of size (N,B) $\otimes \ \mathbb{I}$?

Ideally, I want to be able to calculate these values and understand how it's done!

Apologises for the poor wording of this question!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to learn is how to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) a matrix equation using the Kronecker product
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{vec}(AXB) &= (B^T\otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(X) \\
}$$
Applying this to your example equation yields
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{vec}(Y)
 &= (X^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(A)
  + (I^T\otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(C) \\
y &= (X^T\otimes I)\,a + (I\otimes I)\,c \\
}$$
Now your calculations can be performed on ordinary matrix-vector equations, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} &= (X^T\otimes I) \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial c} &= (I\otimes I) \\
}$$
The standard text for this is "*Matrix Differential Calculus*"
by Magnus & Neudecker.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I assume the Vec(Y) function you state, takes a matrix and converts it to a vector by stacking columns on top of one another? Thank you for the recommendation of the textbook!

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. The Wikipedia link in my answer provides an overview, until you can get ahold of Magnus & Neudecker.